# browser won't load css stylesheet for my local website using express and node

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, express, nodes

[image]

[image]

And the app.js screenshot:
[image]

I tried every possible combination of href and express.static(""); adresses. I either get
a response from a browser saying browser wont allow me to load local files or I get this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the folder name `public` is already contained in the URL of your stylesheet, you must write

```js
app.use("/public", express.static("D:\\Igor\\Desktop\\Angela\\todolist-v1\\public"));
```

Note also that backslashes must be doubled in Javascript strings.

With your current code, the stylesheet is looked up at `D:\Igor\Desktop\Angela\todolist-v1\public\public\css\styles.css`, where it does not exist. This leads to an HTML error page ("Cannot GET ..."), hence the browser complaint about the wrong mime type.

Answer (score 0):

. *If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve.*

Have you installed "path" module??

If not first install it.

1. Do

   const path= require('path')
2. To use a static directory in your app do,

app.use('/public' , express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

3. Now to access assets under public folder in any directory use,

   public/css/style.css